# Inline text and photo

Tags: html, css

I tried to make an image and text stay in the same line, but somehow the image doesn't fit in properly.

I tried wrapping the items together with a div and gave them a display of flex, text-align center and margin from the body 50px. Somehow it looks like this [the result of my method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHOp3.png)

Comment: 1. please add code (html and css), 2. it's not clear what you want to achieve

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you like to achieve?

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.3), rgba(255,255,255,0.3)), url("https://i.imgur.com/K1UPhPm.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
button {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Access To Your Favorite Blockchain Features</h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. <br>
  Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, <br>
  when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. <br>
  It has survived not only five centuries, <br>
  but also the leap into electronic typesetting, <br>
  remaining essentially unchanged.</p>

<button>Learn more</button>
```

I'm sorry, but it's hard to understand the problem without a reference/s